# Tensorflow-Java Image Comparison

Tags: java, image, image-processing, tensorflow, tensor

I am new to tensorflow, so loads of basic doubts :-)

I have two identical images(dogs), I edited one (i.e I cut a small piece of the dog, please don't hate me its in all in the name of science) now I have created a tensor out these two images, When I print the tensor it has the same value, shouldn't it be two different values ? How will I tell the difference between these two images? I want to measure how much and what changed between these two images.

```
Tensor:-
[172, 293, 3, 1]

Code:-
  final Output input = b.constant("input", imgBytes);
  output = b.expandDims(
                  b.cast(b.decodeJpeg(input, 3), DataType.FLOAT),
                  b.constant("make_batch", 3));

  try (Session s = new Session(g)) {
      t = s.runner().fetch(output.op().name()).run().get(0);
  }
  System.out.println("output1="+t.toString());
```

@pyb, Thanks for the code format.

Comment: I indented your code with 4 spaces so it gets formatted.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "it has the same value"? How are you printing out the value of the tensor?  As in, where is the string `[172, 293, 3, 1]` coming from?

Comment: In words of sheldon cooper I made a boo-boo, so editing the post with a more relevant quesiton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Tensor.toString()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/Tensor.html#toString()) does not return the value of the contents of the tensor. It returns a string describing metadata - the shape and type (see linked javadoc).

I suspect the string `[172, 293, 3, 1]` is a truncated form of what `Tensor.toString()` [actually prints](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/Tensor.java#L446), which would be something like `FLOAT tensor with shape [172, 293, 3, 1]`.

If that is the case, you see the same string because both images have the same dimensions (they are 172x293x3 pixel images).

To see the contents of the tensor, see [`Tensor.writeTo`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/Tensor.html#writeTo(java.nio.FloatBuffer)) or [`Tensor.copyTo`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/Tensor.html#copyTo(T))

For example:

```
float[][][] contents = t.copyTo(new float[172][293][3]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(contents));
```

Hope that helps.